# Sending an UIImage to multiplayer through GameCenter

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2, game-center

I have a UIImage which comes from CGContext,
Now i need to send that image through GameCenter and the other player on the other end should receive that image

AnyLink  or Code is accepted.
Kindly do help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the code that connects players so they are able to receive and send NSData?
If so, simply convert the UIImage to NSData and send it.
If not, check this tutorial for gamecenter communication:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12

Comment: I have followed this tutorial and got upto the authentication part now i have to connect the players, Which i do not have. 
I got a small problem here when i am setting the maxPlayers to 10 i am getting error like : The requested operation could not be completed because the match request is invalid.
which is coming from 
- (void)matchmakerViewController:(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Error finding match: %@", error.localizedDescription);    
}

Comment: this tutorial means the above mentioned that @BobDev has provided

Comment: this is another question of which we do not have enough data at all.. please create a new question or try to experiment some more first. I've followed this tutorial myself and had no issues whatsoever.